# Encrypt and Decrypt with different keys - Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm working with the enccc example, I'm able to encrypt and decrypt with a shared key, so the same key is used for both encryption and decryption. I need to use different keys, one to encrypt (like a public key) and another to decrypt (like a private key). Could someone guide me or tell me where I could read about it? Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [crypto/rsa](https://golang.org/src/crypto/rsa/example_test.go) package for encrypting using RSA.